# Current Project Version in Build Settings not updating as expected

Tags: xcode, plist, plistbuddy

**Goal:** To set my target's "Current Project Version" to `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)` so that changing the project's info.plist's `Bundle Version` variable will automatically carry over to the project file.

**How I am doing it:** I am using a script to change my project's info.plist's `CFBundleVersion` using PlistBuddy. Because I want this change to be automatically reflected in the project file, I have set the target's "Current Project Version" to `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`. My understanding is that this is just a pointer to the `CFBundleVersion` from the project's info.plist.

**The problem:** Although the script runs correctly (i.e., the `Bundle Version` variable in the info.plist is updated), the "Current Project Version" never updates, and in fact it displays an empty field instead.

[image]

Why is this not working?

Note that I am explicitly trying to do this **without** using fastlane or agvtool

Comment: "$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION). My understanding is that this variable translates theCFBundleVersion value from the project's info.plist." It sounds like you might have it backwards? Also, remember that what you see in the project is not so important; all that matters in the end is what the info.plist of the _built app_ looks like.

Comment: In my case, it is important that what's in the project's file is accurate and up to date. The goal behind my entire effort is to remove the need to manually fix conflicts that will inevitably arise in a PR where that updates the project's version. If I use a pointer like `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`, then a PR that updates the project's version with my script will not result in conflicts in the project file (which are generally confusing to fix) because the pointer has not changed. With this knowledge in mind, do you know why the version is not being updated correctly in the project file?

Answer (score 3):

`CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` is defined in your project.pbxproj file, not Info.plist . To change it, use agvtool:

```sh
xcrun agvtool new-marketing-version "your.app.version"
xcrun agvtool new-version -all "your.build.number"
```

Or you can use [fastlane increment_version_number](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/increment_version_number/).

Comment: As my post says: "Note that I am explicitly trying to do this without using fastlane or agvtool"

Comment: What tools are you willing to use? PlistBuddy will not help, because it doesn't change the right file. You could try bare-bones `sed`, but why?

Answer (score 1):

The plist is generated from the project file, not the other way around. The plist is (usually) generated every time xcode builds your application, so for most people it is a transient file. If you change your project file's version, then the plist file will stay in sync.

Note that you *can* use PlistBuddy on an Xcode project file, but since it's a bunch of Guids, you have to query your way through the file to get all of the BuildConfigurations that you need to update.

Or, you can use .xcconfig files which will make it much easier to modify the version which Xcode will read in to modify project settings, and then push that into the .plist.